# Linear transformation $f(x) \to f(x+1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is this a linear transformation?
\begin{align*}
\varphi : \mathbb{R}[x] &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]\\
f(x)&\longmapsto f(x+1)
\end{align*}
How I've done:
$$φ((f(x)+g(x)) = φ((f+g)(x)) = (f+g)(x+1)$$
$$φ(f(x)) + φ(g(x)) = f(x+1) + g(x+1)$$
So it's true for addition.
$$φ(n\cdot f(x)) = n\cdot f(x+1)$$
$$n\cdot φ(f(x)) = n\cdot f(x+1)$$
So it's also true for multiplication.
Am i doing it right? Also why can we write like this: $$φ((f(x)+g(x))) = φ((f+g)(x))\,?$$ (i did it similar to our seminar)

Comment: It looks correct (I think the last formula you wrote has a typo, it should be $f(x)+g(x)=(f+g)(x)$; this is simply the definition of the polynomial $f+g$ given two polymolials $f$ and $g$)

Comment: Any operator of the form $\varphi :f(x)\mapsto f(u(x))$ for a fixed function $u$ is linear.

Comment: Maybe what you should consider verifying that $f(x+1)+g(x+1)=(f+g)(x+1)$ if you are not sure on why this is true.

Comment: If you want to prove it like 'with developments' you can show that the results work for every pair $x^m$ and $x^l$ monomials and conclude.